# Is there a way to check if a remote database exists?

Tags: pouchdb

Is there a pouchdb API to check if a remote database exists?

There is a `db.info()` method, but that requires a `db` object and using the following to create a `db` object will also create the target if it doesn't already exist:

`var db = new PouchDB(url);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, just use the [`skip_setup` option](https://pouchdb.com/api.html#options):

```
var db = new PouchDB('http://localhost:5984/i_dont_exist', {skip_setup: true});
db.info()
  .then(console.log.bind(console))
  .catch(console.log.bind(console));
```

This will throw an error:

```
{ 
  status: 404,
  name: 'not_found',
  message: 'missing',
  error: true,
  reason: 'no_db_file'
}
```

Comment: The option has since been changed to `skip_setup` (with an underscore instead of camelCase).